# Can I deploy bamboo.yml YAML specs manually?

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

I am trying to learn how YAML specs works in Bamboo. So far I achieved to deploy the plan following the official documentation. [enter link description here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-bamboo-specs-yaml-stored-in-bitbucket-server-941616819.html)

The documentation explains that you need to create a bitbucket repository, create bamboo.yml, set a new project in bamboo, enable a bamboo specs repository and finally you get your plan created and based in YAML specs.

My question is, can I create a plan.yml and deploy it from other bamboo plan?

For example, for JAVA specs, it is enough to checkout a repo with several *.java specs files and use maven and a pom file to deploy all the plans.

Can I do something similar with YAML specs? To have a folder in some SCM with several *.yml files and deploy them simultaneously. As a result, to have a lot of plans in bamboo deployed and based on the yml files.

Comment: In theory you can because bamboo specs client converts all entities to yaml before sending on the wire. In practice, it would be difficult to adapt their BambooServer#publish method to do that. Nevertheless, it's not impossible by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

yes and no, yaml can't be sent to the server as you can do with java specs. It needs to be committed to the repo first

you also need to have your different project created prior to committing the yaml specs and or have that repo granted access to each individual project or enabled the flag on the linked repo to allow access to all projects in the specs tab.

if this is not an issue,then yes there is no problem defining multiple plans in your bamboo specs yml file, even across multiple projects, as long as they are split up in separate yaml documents (with "---")